# Applet Loading Properly on Refresh not on the first time

Tags: java, security, applet, digital-certificate

I have developed one applet and I am finding a strange behaviour.

The applet is mainly accessing browser certificates and using it for encryption and decryption.

The applet loads on login of the application.

1. When I login in Internet Explorer. 
   The applet loading stops at following point and then closes down automatically.

   basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://phil.etenders.in/securityApplet.jar
   security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
   security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
   network: Cache entry found [url: http://phil.etenders.in/securityApplet.jar, version:    null] prevalidated=false/0

If I open any sample applet from http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/Java/applets.htm 
it stops on following line
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByPolicy called 
    basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByPolicy returns false

1. When I click refresh the applet loads again and it runs successfully.

When I do the above steps in Firefox it does not load after refresh as well.

I have also tried to load sample applets from other websites it has the same problem. When I open any local html files with local applet the same thing works fine.